# SQL and oop in objective-c

Tags: sql, objective-c, database, sqlite

This is probably a stupid question, I tried looking for similar post but I couldn't find any so if there's some.

I'm starting to use SQL, it's quite easy but how can I save an entire object in it?

I try to explain better. If I want to save an instance of a "car" object should I just save its primitive values or is there a way to save the entire object?

Also, which SQL software you guys suggest to use? I only tried with Mac embedded sqlite

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of thoughts:

1. If you're going to do SQLite programming in Objective-C, you should consider [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb). That makes SQLite programming much easier.

   Generally, though, [Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) is the preferred object persistence technology.
2. But assuming you wanted to save an object in a SQLite table, you can store the object in your database as a blob by creating an archive and saving that in your database:

   - Create an archive (see [Archives and Serializations Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000047i)):

     ```
     Car *car = [[Car alloc] init];
     car.make = @"Honda";
     car.model = @"Accord";
     car.year = 1998;

     NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:car];
     ```

     But for that to work, you have to implement the `initWithCoder` and the `encodeWithCoder` methods for your `Car` class as described in the [Encoding and Decoding Objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Articles/codingobjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000948-BCIHBJDE) section:

     ```
     - (NSArray *)propertyNames
     {
         return @[@"make", @"model", @"year"];
     }

     - (id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
     {
         self = [super init];
         if (self) {
             for (NSString *key in [self propertyNames]) {
                 [self setValue:[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:key] forKey:key];
             }
         }

         return self;
     }

     - (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
     {
         for (NSString *key in [self propertyNames]) {
             [aCoder encodeObject:[self valueForKey:key] forKey:key];
         }
     }
     ```
   - You can save this as a blob in your database. Use `sqlite3_bind_blob` or, easier, use FMDB:

     ```
     NSString *documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
     NSString *path          = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"cars.sqlite"];

     FMDatabase *database = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:path];
     [database open];
     [database executeUpdate:@"create table if not exists cars (data blob)"];
     [database executeUpdate:@"insert into cars (data) values (?)", data];
     ```
   - You can read this from the database at a later point (using `sqlite3_column_blob` and `sqlite3_column_bytes`, or, again, using FMDB makes your life easier):

     ```
     FMResultSet *rs = [database executeQuery:@"select data from cars"];
     while ([rs next])
     {
         NSData *carData = [rs dataForColumnIndex:0];
         Car *carFromDatabase = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:carData];
         NSLog(@"%@, %@, %d", carFromDatabase.make, carFromDatabase.model, carFromDatabase.year);
     }
     ```
3. Having shown you how you could do store the object as a blob, I'd discourage you from doing that. (lol). I'd encourage you to create a SQLite data model that mirrors the object model, and store the individual properties in separate columns of the table.

Or better, use Core Data.

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look at core data [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html)

It makes working with sqlite very easy and is supported on Mac and iOS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the VARBINARY(MAX) field type in SQL Server, if you like. You can store any type of object in there, up to 2 GB in size.

To access it, you can use ADO.NET - something like this:

```
object yourMysteryObject = (whatever you like it to be);

MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(memStm);

sw.Write(yourMysteryObject);

SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO TableName(VarBinaryColumn) VALUES (@VarBinary)", sqlConnection);

sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@VarBinary", SqlDbType.VarBinary, Int32.MaxValue);

sqlCmd.Parameters["@VarBinary"].Value = memStream.GetBuffer();

sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```